# I would like to research different companies for a service, compare them and present a proposal

Tags: windows, web-apps, research

I am currently researching enterprise phone systems for my company. right now i am using Miro (whiteboard) to bring in pdfs, images and data. I have make a large table and started to add features for a couple companies but I am realizing fast that this is not an easy way to do this. I am having to create all the tables in Miro manually and its tedious to get the format correct. I really like miro for the fact I can organize it how i want, attach items and layout images etc.

Is there any software that can do this? I have many other things in my company we are looking to change and I'm going to have to do this for them all. The **end goal** is to layout all the options, costs, benefits of each options to management to make a decision. I need to be able to do this with data and graphics.

that is the other problem with Miro. Once i get everything organized on my board when i need to present it I'm going to have to reformat everything. I can export a board to a pdf which might be an option but haven't made it that far yet.

I would also like to be able to collaborate with other members in my team that are researching as well. Miro does offer this ability which is another reason I am currently using it.

I know there is proposal software out [there](https://www.g2.com/categories/proposal?trending=) but all of those seem to focus on creating the end proposal not the researching it. Maybe there is nothing out there to do both? If not what would be good for the research?

[image]

[image]